# Woocommerce get attribute custom field in wc attribute labels function

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

```
add_filter('woocommerce_attribute_label', 'custom_attribute_label', 10, 3);
function custom_attribute_label($label, $name, $product) {
    $term_meta = get_term_meta($name, 'attribute_description', true);
    switch ($label)  {
        case 'size':
            $label .= '<div class="custom-label">' . __('MY TEXT AFTER LOGO', 'woocommerce') . '</div>';
            break;
        case 'color':
            $label .= '<div class="custom-label">' . __('MY TEXT AFTER COLOR', 'woocommerce') . '</div>';
            break;
    }

    return $label;
}
```

Hello, is it possible to get custom registered field into attribute backend page in `woocommerce_attribute_label` hook.
Field is with id '**attribute_description**', and I am stuck with a way to show frontend.

Any help will be appreciated!

[image]

Code for registered field ( I follow online topic and learned from it ):

```
// Add variation description
function my_edit_wc_attribute_my_field() {
    $id = isset( $_GET['edit'] ) ? absint( $_GET['edit'] ) : 0;
    $value = $id ? get_option( "wc_attribute_attribute_description-$id" ) : '';
    ?>
<div id="attr-desc">
        <tr class="form-field">
            <th scope="row" valign="top">
                <label for="attribute-description">Attribute Description</label>
            </th>
            <td>
                <textarea name="attribute_description" id="attribute-description" rows="5" cols="40"><?php echo esc_attr( $value ); ?></textarea>
                <!--<input name="my_field" id="my-field" value="<?php //echo esc_attr( $value ); ?>" />-->
                <p class="description">Add unique description that will appear in balloon field in single product page.</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
</div>
<script>
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('#attr-desc').appendTo('.form-field:eq(1)');
        //$('#attr-desc').hide();
    });
</script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_attribute_fields', 'my_edit_wc_attribute_my_field' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_edit_attribute_fields', 'my_edit_wc_attribute_my_field' );

// Save variation description
function my_save_wc_attribute_my_field( $id ) {
    if ( is_admin() && isset( $_POST['attribute_description'] ) ) {
        $option = "wc_attribute_attribute_description-$id";
        update_option( $option, sanitize_text_field( $_POST['attribute_description'] ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_attribute_added', 'my_save_wc_attribute_my_field' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_attribute_updated', 'my_save_wc_attribute_my_field' );

// Delete option, when attribute is deleted
add_action( 'woocommerce_attribute_deleted', function ( $id ) {
    delete_option( "wc_attribute_attribute_description-$id" );
});

// Then for example, on a taxonomy/term archive page, you can get the My Field value like so:
/*
$term = get_queried_object();
$attr_id = wc_attribute_taxonomy_id_by_name( $term->taxonomy );
$my_field = get_option( "wc_attribute_my_field-$attr_id" );
*/
```

Comment: Is it possible to show us how you've registered that "custom field"?

Comment: @Ruvee Sure, topic is updated :)

Comment: I was going to reproduce it on my end exactly the way you've got it set up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little tricky how you save the `Attribute Description` because you save it in the options table.

You are saving in option with an id of attribute `wc_attribute_attribute_description-$id` so you have to follow the same procedure to get from option and for that, you need the id of that attribute.

In the `woocommerce_attribute_label` filter hook you only get the `$name` of the attribute. so we have to get attribute taxonomy id. and, for that you can use `wc_attribute_taxonomy_id_by_name()` function.

```
$id = wc_attribute_taxonomy_id_by_name( $name );
```

**Complete code.**

```
function custom_attribute_label($label, $name, $product) {

    $id = wc_attribute_taxonomy_id_by_name( $name );

    $value = get_option( "wc_attribute_attribute_description-$id" );

    switch ($name)  {
        case 'pa_test2':
            $label .= '<div class="custom-label">' . $value . '</div>';
            break;
    }

    return $label;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_attribute_label', 'custom_attribute_label', 10, 3);

// Add variation description
function my_edit_wc_attribute_my_field() {
    $id = isset( $_GET['edit'] ) ? absint( $_GET['edit'] ) : 0;
    $value = $id ? get_option( "wc_attribute_attribute_description-$id" ) : '';
    ?>
    <div id="attr-desc">
            <tr class="form-field">
                <th scope="row" valign="top">
                    <label for="attribute-description">Attribute Description</label>
                </th>
                <td>
                    <textarea name="attribute_description" id="attribute-description" rows="5" cols="40"><?php echo esc_attr( $value ); ?></textarea>
                    <p class="description">Add unique description that will appear in balloon field in single product page.</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </div>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($) {
            $('#attr-desc').appendTo('.form-field:eq(1)');
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_attribute_fields', 'my_edit_wc_attribute_my_field' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_edit_attribute_fields', 'my_edit_wc_attribute_my_field' );

// Save variation description
function my_save_wc_attribute_my_field( $id ) {
    if ( is_admin() && isset( $_POST['attribute_description'] ) ) {
        $option = "wc_attribute_attribute_description-$id";
        update_option( $option, sanitize_text_field( $_POST['attribute_description'] ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_attribute_added', 'my_save_wc_attribute_my_field' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_attribute_updated', 'my_save_wc_attribute_my_field' );
```

**Note**

I have reproduced the entire case so I have added the `test2` attribute so do not forget to change `pa_test2` to your attribute name in the `woocommerce_attribute_label` filter hook.

**Tested and works**

**Backend taxonomy name**

[image]

**Backend Attribute Description**

[image]

**Single product page**

[image]

Comment: Neat solution...

Comment: @bhautic how can I display field value on product page?